# Can I change the host name of a system running SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Does the change of the host name of the server impact the functioning of Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Can you become more specific please? What do you mean by changing the hostname? What do you mean by impact the functioning of the server? The applications that use the old hostname to connect to your server won't be able to connect to it anymore!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are some additional steps that you need to perform after changing the host name.

I could not find the relevant documentation for SQL Server 2012 online any more, but here is the official document for SQL Server 2016-2019:

- [Rename a Computer that Hosts a Stand-Alone Instance of SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/rename-a-computer-that-hosts-a-stand-alone-instance-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-2016)

---

In a nutshell, you need to execute

```
sp_dropserver <old_name\instancename>;  
GO  
sp_addserver <new_name\instancename>, local;  
GO
```

to update system metadata and then restart SQL Server.

Additional steps (see the linked document above) might be necessary if you use:

- a failover cluster,
- replication,
- Reporting Services,
- database mirroring,
- Windows groups containing a hard-coded reference to the computer name,
- remote logins,
- linked server configurations or
- named pipes.

Obviously, the connection strings of any clients connecting to your server will need to be updated as well.

Comment: @taoufik333 Please accept Heinzi's answer if it resolved your question.